# Cordova Error Android Version - admobpro plugin issue

Tags: cordova, plugins

Thanks for reading.

I create a new cordova app.
Once I add the admobpro plugin using the below command I am getting the below error.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Can someone please give me some idea how I can fix this. Thanks for your help.

**Please note that I am using Cordova CLS and Command Prompt to develop the app.**

**Full Error BELOW**

Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Dropbox\AOTSInc\MobileDevelopment\Projects\Christian\TamilChristianSongs\Code\TamilChristianSongs\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-bas
e\10.0.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png into C:\Dropbox\AOTSInc\MobileDevelopment\Projects\Christian\TamilChristianSongs\Code\TamilChristianSongs\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

BUILD FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Dropbox\AOTSInc\MobileDevelopment\Projects\Christian\TamilChristianSongs\Code\TamilChristianSongs\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-b
  >   ase\10.0.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png into C:\Dropbox\AOTSInc\MobileDevelopment\Projects\Christian\TamilChristianSongs\Code\TamilChristianSongs\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_goo
  >   gle_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Total time: 5.269 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Which version of cordova CLI are you using?

Comment: Cordova 6.0.0. also this issue is coming only after i add admobpro plugin. Before adding it its working perfectly.